# Positioned Text issue

Tags: flutter, text, flutter-layout

I am trying to make shadow to my text but some weird thing happended like below image;

[image]

Regular text short then positioned one, how can I correct that?

My code:

```
 Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0, bottom: 4),
       width: 175,
       alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
       child: Column(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
               children: <Widget>[
                         Stack(
                         children: <Widget>[
                         Positioned(
                          left: 1.0,
                          top: 2.0,
                           child: Text("${snapshot.data.results[index].title}",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),maxLines: 1, textAlign: TextAlign.left,),),
                                                              Text("${snapshot.data.results[index].title}", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),maxLines: 1, textAlign: TextAlign.left,), ],),
                   Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                         Positioned(
                           left: 1.0,
                           top: 2.0,
                          child: Text("(${snapshot.data.results[index].releaseDate.toString().substring(0,4)})",
                                                                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),maxLines: 1, textAlign: TextAlign.left),),
                          Text("(${snapshot.data.results[index].releaseDate.toString().substring(0,4)})", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),maxLines: 1, textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                            ],
                           ),
                          ],
                       ),
                 ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to use Positioned, instead you can use de TextStyle like this:

```
Text("YourText",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,shadows: [
            Shadow(color:Colors.black,blurRadius: 0,offset: Offset(0,2)),
          ])),
```